# How to send dict-like string as python parameter in powershell command

Tags: python, powershell

In general, I can call python like this:

`python ABC.py "{'a':1}"`

then, in python I use `ast.literal_eval` to get dict.

how can I do this in powershell?

I have escape with `"`,but I can't get in the python.

`` start-process powershell -ArgumentList "-command python ABC.py '{`"a`":1}'" ``

Answer (score 0):

not sure why I am unable to replicate, maybe its python issue but the following code is in my trash.py file

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a','--asd',help='asd',required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print(type(eval(args['asd'])))
```

and when i run this from my power shell with the following command

```
python trash.py --a "{'a':1}"
```

it gave me the expected output :

```
<class 'dict'>
```

I am using python 3.6.8

Comment: I think the problem is how to add dict-like string argument to python by using ```start-process```